# Alternative ST_NumGeometries in type geography

Tags: postgis, geography

In PostGIS (2.1.8) I use function `ST_NumGeometries` for nums of count `geometry`. This function have one argument 'geometry' type.
I need this function for `geography` type. I looked for but I didn't find it.

Comment: Have you tried to cast into geometry first? You can do it on-the-fly.

Comment: I don't understand. You mean like this? ST_NumGeometries(geog::geometry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_NumGeometries.html)

> `ST_NumGeometries` — If **geometry** is a `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION` (or `MULTI*`) return the number of geometries, for single geometries will return 1, otherwise return NULL.

So, as mentioned in the comments, simply cast first with `::geometry`

```
SELECT ST_NumGeometries( geog::geometry )
FROM CAST( ST_Multi(ST_MakePoint(1,1)) AS geography) AS geog;

SELECT ST_NumGeometries( geog::geometry )
FROM CAST( ST_ForceCollection(ST_MakePoint(1,1)) AS geography) AS geog;
```

Comment: @ondrusu please mark as chosen if it answered your question.

Comment: I am sorry I have wrong score on Stackoverflow.